# ¿Cómo podría imprimir arreglo en Python multiplicando el vector original por 1 numero?

Tags: python, array, bucle-for, numpy

Tengo la siguiente asignación que me pide hacer un programa que reciba como entrada 10 números, los copie a otro array multiplicados por 3 y muestre el segundo array.

Tengo el siguiente código pero al completar el segundo array se imprime vacío

¿Alguna sugerencia?

```
import numpy as np

suma=0
lista= np.array([])

for i in range(10):
    valor=float(input("Digite los valores de su vector:"))
    suma=suma+valor
    np.append(lista, valor)
    
print("Los valores multiplicados por 3 son los siguientes:",lista*3)
```

PS.

Utilicé el `.multiply()` de Numpy luego de agregar un escalar como variable y multipliqué la lista por este valor y listo.

```
resultado = np.multiply(lista,b)
```

Answer (score 1):

No necesariamente tienes que utilizar `numpy` puesto que no estarás trabajando  con muchos datos. Como deseas multiplicar x3 10 elementos introducidos por el usuario puedes recurrir a un bucle for
Y en cada iteración el `valor ingresado` aplicarle la correspondiente operación matemática así:

```
lista=[]

for i in range(10):
    valor=float(input("Digite los valores de su vector:"))
    valorx3 = valor*3
    lista.append(valorx3)
    
print("Los valores multiplicados son: ", lista)
```

### Explicación

Como se puede observar elimino la importación de la librería numpy para ahorrar espacio en memoria y se procede a crear una lista donde se almacenarán los números multiplicados, paso seguido se crea un bucle for que realizará 10 iteraciones para que pida 10 valores distintos los cuales paso seguido se multiplicarán por 3 y se añadirán a la lista creada anteriormente. Finalmente imprimimos el resultado.

Comment: Las listas en Python utilizan más memoria que los arreglos de numpy

Comment: si bien funciona, da toda la sensación que quiere usar numpy, más allá de las diferencias lógicas.

Comment: @HeytalePazguato ¿Aunque la lista sea muy pequeña? Puesto que se estaría cargando un modulo.

Comment: Seguramente si se utilizan pocas listas y pequeñas sería menos memoria utilizar listas que arreglos pero en general si hay que trabajar con arreglos es mejor utilizar directamente numpy ya que la memoria se optimiza y también las operaciones son más rápidas.

Answer (score 1):

hay cosas que no entendí el porque las haces

```
import numpy as np
#suma=0  esto no sé para que está
lista= np.array([])

for i in range(10):
   lista=np.append(lista,float(input("Digite los valores de su vector:")))
```

se debe declarar que devolverá lo agregado, en este caso el propio array y eliminé lo que no entendí ya que no lo vi en el planteo.

```
print("Los valores multiplicados por 3 son los siguientes:",lista*3)
```

si bien se obtiene el resultado el planteo dice:

PS.
Utilicé el .multiply() de Numpy luego de agregar un escalar como variable y multipliqué la lista por este valor y listo.

resultado = np.multiply(lista,b)

por lo tanto debería ser:

```
print("Los valores multiplicados por 3 son los siguientes:",np.multiply(lista,3))
```